# Draw Lines above faces

Tags: c++, opengl, glm-math

I am loading a mesh with modern OpenGL (vertex and fragment shader) and I have a color uniform.

I draw the mesh with depthtest then:

```
glEnable(GL_DEPTH_TEST);
glDepthFunc(GL_LESS);
```

and in the draw loop I draw the faces first with a gray color, then the lines with a black color like this:

```
GLint myLoc = glGetUniformLocation(shader_util.get_program_id(), "color");

// draw loop
glm::vec4 vColor { 0.7f, 0.7f, 0.7f, 1.0f };
glProgramUniform4fv(shader_util.get_program_id(), myLoc, 1, glm::value_ptr(vColor));

pMesh->draw_faces();

vColor = { 0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f };
glProgramUniform4fv(shader_util.get_program_id(), myLoc, 1, glm::value_ptr(vColor));

pMesh->draw_wireframe();
```

And these are the draw methods of the mesh:

```
void Mesh::draw_wireframe()
{
  glDrawArrays(GL_LINE_LOOP, 0, (GLsizei) mVertexIndices.size());
}

void Mesh::draw_faces()
{
  glDrawArrays(GL_TRIANGLES, 0, (GLsizei)mVertexIndices.size());
}
```

The problem is, that the lines look like this with kind of interruptions in drawing:

[image]

Any advice how to fix this?

Comment: The basic problem is z-fighting.  Don't have time to post a full answer right now but... the fix in this particular case is probably a [stencil buffer](https://learnopengl.com/Advanced-OpenGL/Stencil-testing).  Draw the wire-frame as now *and* to the stencil buffer, then only draw the face where both depth and stencil tests pass (depending on exactly how you configure things).

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to avoid Z-fighting in distance?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32938159/how-to-avoid-z-fighting-in-distance)

Comment: @G.M.: Ok thx, but most of these function are deprecated in modern OpenGL.Do you know a way to solve this using shaders?

Comment: Which functions are deprecated?

Answer (score 1):

I found a solution with glPolygonOffset:

```
glEnable(GL_POLYGON_OFFSET_FILL);
glPolygonOffset(1.0f, 1.0f);

glm::vec4 vColor { 0.7f, 0.7f, 0.7f, 1.0f };
GLint myLoc = glGetUniformLocation(shader_util.get_program_id(), "color");
glProgramUniform4fv(shader_util.get_program_id(), myLoc, 1, glm::value_ptr(vColor));

pMesh->draw_faces();

glDisable(GL_POLYGON_OFFSET_FILL);

vColor = { 0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f };
glProgramUniform4fv(shader_util.get_program_id(), myLoc, 1, glm::value_ptr(vColor));

pMesh->draw_wireframe();
```

But I will search for a similar solution in fragment shader.

[image]

Comment: I think you should be able to use transformations if you want to do it in the shader: https://learnopengl.com/Getting-started/Transformations. In particular scaling. Something like glm::mat4 trans = glm::mat4(1.0f);
trans = glm::scale(trans, glm::vec3(1, 1.01, 1)); (I use python and I do it on a flat mesh, so not sure what the effect on a sphere would  be if you scale all directions?)