# OpenTK/GL Texture has weird lines going through it unless camera is in a sweetspot

Tags: c#, opengl, textures, opentk

There's a lot of code so I'm not going to put it here. I'm just wondering if anyone has had a similar issue to this and how they solved it.

I'm trying to create a 3d scene in C# using OpenGL and have got lighting working as well as basic primitive models and more complex models. But now I'm trying to texture the walls and I'm getting these weird lines running through the texture. Whenever I move the camera the lines change and glitch around but are always vertical lines.

I have noticed there is a sweetspot for the camera when looking directly at the wall and being at the right distance from it.
[The sweetspot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/u4KFg.png)

[Rotate left - lines appear](https://i.stack.imgur.com/l1FY2.jpg)

[Camera at right angle but wrong distance - texture dissapears](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qMo0n.png)

I know it's not a lot to go off so I'm not expecting anyone to be able to tell me exactly what to do. I just want to know if anyone knows what these weird results could be. I'm thinking I may need to change some texture parameters but not sure which ones. Is there a clipping parameter or something? Any sort of guidance here would be appreciated

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Comment: Is the texture supposed to look like blue lines \\\\\\\\ or is it not supposed to look like that?

Answer (score 0):

This looks a lot like [z-fighting](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32938159/how-to-avoid-z-fighting-in-distance), which is caused by rendering two surfaces at the same depth. Numerical instability will cause some areas to be drawn over others in a changing pattern.

If you can find out which surfaces you're drawing twice and get rid of one of them, then this problem should go away.